# `show` record without deriving Show

Tags: haskell

Quite often I need to print something while debugging and unless the datatype I need to see derives `Show` I can't print it. For some datatypes I can't add `deriving (Show)` to the definition because it may be in a library or somewhere else I can't get to.

Is there anyway I can print these datatypes for debugging?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you give an example of a library with a type that's missing a `Show` instance you'd like to have?

Comment: The types created by Yesod models. I think these are defined in template Haskell so I can't get to them.

Comment: Oh? It looks like all the examples here have a `deriving Show` clause https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Standalone deriving

A `deriving` clause on the type definition isn't the only way to derive. You can also use the [`StandaloneDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=standalonederiving#ghc-flag--XStandaloneDeriving) GHC language extension.

```
λ> :set -XStandaloneDeriving

λ> data Person = Human { name :: String, age :: Int } | Dog { goodPupper :: Bool }

λ> deriving instance Show Person

λ> Human "Chris" 31
Human {name = "Chris", age = 31}
```

### Generics

If the type has a `Generic` instance, you can stringify it with the [`gshowsPrecdefault`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.12.1/docs/Generics-Deriving-Show.html#v:gshowsPrecdefault) function from the [generic-deriving](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving) package.

```
λ> import GHC.Generics
λ> import Generics.Deriving.Show

λ> data Person = Human { name :: String, age :: Int } | Dog { goodPupper :: Bool } deriving Generic

λ> putStrLn $ gshowsPrecdefault 0 (Dog True) ""
Dog {goodPupper = True}
```

### GHCi :force

You can use the `:force` command in GHCi to inspect a value.

```
λ> data Person = Human { name :: String, age :: Int } | Dog { goodPupper :: Bool }

λ> x = Human "Chris" 31

λ> x
<interactive>:17:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show Person) arising from a use of ‘print’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

λ> :force x
x = <Human> "Chris" 31
```

See [*Breakpoints and inspecting variables*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#breakpoints-and-inspecting-variables) in the GHC manual.

Comment: Force seems helpful but most of the time I need to do this within my tests run from `stack test` and not ghci.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make your datatype an instance of `Show` if you want to print it in any way.  If you don't want to derive `Show` you can always implement it yourself.

```
data Foo = Bar

instance Show Foo where
  show Bar = "This is Bar"

main = print f where f = Bar
```

Comment: Is there any way to not set the text it will show and instead show all the fields inside Bar like deriving show would have?

Comment: @Qwertie yes, you only need to not set the text it will show and instead show all the fields inside Bar, like `show (Bar x y z) = "Bar " ++ show x ++ ' ':show y ++ ' ':show z`

Comment: Formatting nitpicking: `<!-- language: lang-haskell -->` [doesn't actually add Haskell highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267272/2751851).

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely print things without `Show` instances.

```
data MyType a = MyType Int a
showMyType :: (a -> String) -> MyType a -> String
showMyType f (MyType n a) =
  "MyType " ++ show n ++ " (" ++ f a ++ ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot of deep functions with type parameters such as `n` (for number type), but no `Show n` constraint on the function.
This function is eventually called with something like `Double`.

To look at the value without adding Show constraint on the function and all of its dependencies, you can use this:

```
forceTraceShowId :: forall a b. Show b => a -> a
forceTraceShowId x = trace (show $ unsafeCoerce @a @b x) x
```

And call `forceTraceShowId` like `forceTraceShowId @_ @Double`

Alternatively, you can set the breakpoint at the desired line/function and display value of the variable `x` at runtime with `:force x`